# what does objdump mean by 'unsafe'?

Tags: objdump

objdump, run on a relatively modern 64-bit linux system, complains as follows about one of our shared libs:

use of unsafe function-scope static in ‘lib64/libwhatever.so’.

What does that mean?

The man page doesn't mention 'unsafe' or 'function-scope' anywhere I can see.

Answer (score 0):

"function-scope" doesn't appear in the binutils source tree, from what I can see.  So maybe this comes from a vendor patch; in which case you ought to ask your vendor.